# where condition with OR clause on primary keys

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm trying to use single query to fetch records based on `empid` or `deptid`.
The input to my stored procedure could be either `empid` or `deptid`. 
The `empid` is the primary key clustered indexed column in `employees` table.

The query is taking time and I stopped executing it, Just wanted to know is this valid scenario considering or clause on primary keys?

I'm using sybase

```
declare @emp_id int null,
@dept_id int null

select emp.* from employees emp
where
(@emp_id is null or emp.emp_id = @emp_id)
and (@dept_id is null or emp.dept_id = @dept_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause will not produce what you think it should. As is, it is trying to include all records that have both of your *entered* values as `null`, which is likely not what you want. (Which records would those be, anyways?)

In order to get all the records that have either entered value, you need to switch the `is null`s to `is not null` and swap the `and`s and `or`s.

```
declare @emp_id int null,
        @dept_id int null

select emp.* from employees emp
where (@emp_id is not null and emp.emp_id = @emp_id)
   or (@dept_id is not null and emp.dept_id = @dept_id)
```

SQL's three-value logic is often one of the most confusing things about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure should be something like

```
create procedure usp_GetEmployeeDetails
  @SearchId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT EMP.*, 'EmployeeID' AS 'MatchedColumn'
    FROM 
    EMPLOYEE
    WHERE EmployeeID = @SearchId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT EMP.*, 'DepartmentID' AS 'MatchedColumn'
    FROM 
    EMPLOYEE
    WHERE DepartmentID = @SearchId
END
```

This would cater for the scenario where you have the same EmployeeID and DepartmentId. However, I would suggest two different stored procedures for two different parameters - one to retrieve employee details by EmployeeId and the other by DepartmentId.